# Using JSON data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have some JSON data:

```
data1=[
{"date": 1396828800, "impressions": 49145385},
{"date": 1396915200, "impressions": 46704447},
{"date": 1397001600, "impressions": 47181000},
{"date": 1397088000, "impressions": 47337965},
{"date": 1397174400, "impressions": 51129266},
{"date": 1397260800, "impressions": 60547397},
{"date": 1397347200, "impressions": 62217077},
{"date": 1397433600, "impressions": 49145385},
{"date": 1397520000, "impressions": 46704447},
{"date": 1397606400, "impressions": 47181000},
{"date": 1397692800, "impressions": 47337965},
{"date": 1397779200, "impressions": 51129266},
{"date": 1397865600, "impressions": 60547397}
];
```

and I want to display this in Highcharts. Here is the template I am working off of: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/j8cTE/9/

How can I get this data into the highcharts chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some processesing of your data to get it into the format highcharts wants.

```
for (var i=0;i< data1.length;i++) {
    data1[i] = [data1[i].date, data1[i].impressions];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8cTE/10/

and then use it as the series:

```
    series: 
    [{
        data: data1   
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
series: 
        [{
            data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 01), 1000],
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 02), 1000],
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 03), 1000],
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 04), 1000]]    
        },
        { 
            data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 01), 1000],
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 02), 1000],
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 03), 1000],
                    [Date.UTC(2014, 0, 04), 1000]]
        }
        ]
```

with

```
series: [{data: data}]
```

Also, you will need to reformat your data to look like what they have shown there:

```
["date", 49145385]
```

instead of

```
{"date": 1396828800, "impressions": 49145385}
```